# Императив ешь — этимология

Tags: этимология

Откуда в императиве "ешь" взязась буква "ш"? Есть ли в русском ещё императивы с "шь" на конце?

Answer (score 1):

Вики об императиве: «В славянском языке формами старого повелительного наклонения можно считать только формы нетематических глаголов вроде виждь, яждь, даждь, веждь, русские вишь (вижь), ешь (вместо еж). Остальные славянские формы повелительного наклонения суть формы желательного (оптатив).  … В русском языке оптатив не выделяется в качестве самостоятельного наклонения…. Оптатив по модальности» может стоять «между повелительным и сослагательным наклонениями…»

Примеры с "шь": даешь (планов громадье), идешь (куда подальше), услышь (меня хорошая), (у)тешь, (об/раз)рушь, опояшь.

Примеры с "жь": (по)мажь, (от)режь, (раз)множь, вынь да положь.